# How to use JNDI to obtain a new Stateful Session Bean, in EJB3?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi, stateful-session-bean

I'm trying to use JNDI to obtain a new Stateful Session Bean in a servlet (as a local variable).  My `doGet()` method has the following:

```
Bean bean = (Bean) new InitialContext().lookup("beanName");
```

I've tried including `java:comp/env` but all of my attempts have led to naming exceptions.

I'm attempting to bind the bean in the `@Stateful` annotation, using various guesses like `@Stateful(name="beanName")` and `@Stateful(mappedName="beanName")`

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  If this question is interesting to others, I'll answer it next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I needed was to use the `@EJB` annotation on the servlet at the class level, as follows:

```
@EJB(name="beanName", beanInterface = Bean.class)
```

Then lookup in the service method can happen using the name bound by the `@EJB` annotation:

```
Bean beanInstance = (Bean) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/beanName");
```

There is no need for anything in the Bean class itself, other than the plain `@Stateful` annotation.

Comment: hello... I was wondering how you solved the problem, I tried your solution but it doesn't work for me!

Comment: @Marci-man sorry to hear it. I certainly don't remember anything that I didn't record, that was over 30 months ago. Maybe you can ask a new question with your specifics.

Comment: I solved it .... I let Netbeans do it for me. I right clicked in editor and selected insert code, and from there I selected Business Bean and then I selected my business bean and Netbeans took care of everything. It created an instance of the bean and a method that returned an initialized bean! I have a kind of love hate relationship with Netbeans :D